# moment.js is doing weird things when parsing a badly formatted date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

If I specify `YYYY-MM-17` as a date to moment.js, it says it is a valid date:

```
var myMoment = moment('YYYY-MM-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(myMoment.isValid()); // -> true

console.log(myMoment.get('year')); // -> 2017
console.log(myMoment.get('month')); // -> 0
console.log(myMoment.get('day')); // -> 0
```

https://jsfiddle.net/seu6x3k3/3/

I'm also seeing different results on different browsers.  According to the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> ... we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, then fall back to `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

This is not what I am seeing.  When natively specifying a date using the same format:

```
var date = new Date('YYYY-MM-17'); // -> NaN

console.log(date.getYear()); // -> NaN
console.log(date.getMonth()); // -> NaN
console.log(date.getDay()); // -> NaN
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3p5x1qn3/

Comment: I tried answering this but I had to give up when I discovered that Moment treats `moment('foo-bar-17')` as invalid but `moment('foo-bar-1')` through to `moment('foo-bar-12')` as January to December 1st 2001. I'm not sure what different results you're seeing, but it may be related to [this question I answered a few weeks back](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32007167/1317805).

Comment: Thanks James.  Found out there is a 'strict' option for the parse.  Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a strict option.  From the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly.

```
var myMoment = moment('YYYY-MM-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);

console.log(myMoment.isValid()); // -> false

console.log(myMoment.get('year')); // -> 2016
console.log(myMoment.get('month')); // -> 4
console.log(myMoment.get('day')); // -> 0
```

https://jsfiddle.net/seu6x3k3/5/